# How can I rollback single Charge Stripe transaction via API?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

As mentioned, I want to undo a transaction if the customer cancels the order?
I am working on PHP Laravel.

Comment: Is this after the customer is charged? If so you can issue a refund https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_refund

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [stripe's refund API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_refund). All you need to do is pass the charge id of the transaction using which the customer ordered the item. You could optionally pass a refund amount to the API just in case you do not want to give a full refund.

Also, [refunds take 5-10 business days](https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-do-i-issue-refunds).

Comment: And I get `charge id` from the `Charge` method creation right?

Comment: Yes. The output of charge method can be got as a json, and the json has a key 'id' with a value something like 'ch_17lG2G2U2dD4WTJFJx21ppaS'. That is the id you need to pass as input to the refund API.

Answer (score 3):

A good approach is to use the power of auth, capture feature of Stripe.

From the stripe documentation:

Authorizing is just a question of setting the **capture** property to **false**

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
    'amount' => 999,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'description' => 'Example charge',
    'source' => $token,
    'capture' => false,
]);
```

and then after everything is processed you could do as the following:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve('ch_4vV97HFFTQXFaYb9KAMP');
$charge->capture();
```

documentation: [Stripe - Auth and Capture](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#auth-capture)

Comment: How i could roll back a transaction before capturing? i know once i capture it i could refund it but i want to cancel it before i capture it.

Comment: @Lai Zada Look at the first answer.  you can refund a non-captured charge too to prevent the capture later. 
They could however take longer than letting the authorization fades away but if you are sure that you will not capture the payment that is the best practice.